# Constructive approach to complete intersections

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, constructive-mathematics

Let $K$ be a field (probably of positive characteristic) and consider the ring $R=K[\![x_1,\dotsc,x_n]\!]$.  Suppose we have an ideal $I=(f_1,\dotsc,f_n)$ (with the same $n$ as before).  Suppose we also have elements $a_{ij}$ and $k>0$ with $\sum_ja_{ij}f_j=x_i^k$ for all $i$, which proves that $R/I$ has finite dimension over $K$.  Standard results from commutative algebra now tell me that the sequence $f_1,\dotsc,f_n$ is regular (and more precisely, that the associated Koszul complex is exact except in degree zero) and that the socle of $R/I$ has dimension one.  The standard proofs tend to use prime ideals, injective envelopes and so on, so they are not very constructive.  Is there a more direct and equational approach to this?

There is some relevant theory involving Jacobians but it seems not to work well in positive characteristic so I would prefer to avoid it.

Comment: Did you look at Lombardi and Quitté's book on constructive algebra ([arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.04832) here)? Your question sounds like something they may have done.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I looked at that book before, and did not find anything directly useful.  I just looked again more closely and I now think that the discussion of the Bezout matrix on pages 337 and 366 is potentially relevant.  However, I think that a substantial amount of additional work would be needed to answer my question.

Comment: May be an alternate procedure is as follows. Your condition says $R/I$ is a finite dimensional $k$-vector space. First, you have to find a basis of this constructively. Then an argument used to prove Weierstrass preparation theorem will show that this basis can be lifted (this is not quite constructive, but at least successively improving the basis upto higher and higher oreder) to a basis of $R$ over $S=k[[u_1,\ldots,u_n]], u_i\mapsto f_i$. This gives the exactness of the Koszul.

Comment: [A lot of what you write is unfamiliar to me...but in principle there is much constructivity in algebra.] For my Master's thesis I wrote up how one can construct the complex $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{C}_p$, by first extending the $p$-adic valuation on $\mathbb{Q}$ to the algebraic numbers (result is called $ \mathbb{A}_p$), and then forming $\mathbb{C}_p$ as the metric completion of $ \mathbb{A}_p$. This illustrates a possible strategy: first restrict your question to discrete fields (decidable equality of elements), and then try to lift answers to the completion field.

Comment: Also, your question calls to mind the wonderful effectivity of [Gröbner bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gröbner_basis), when dealing with equations and polynomial elimination. But I'm quite unsure if that is what you could mean (can't hurt to mention it I hope).

Comment: @FrankWaaldijk For any given sequence $f_1,\dotsc,f_n$, I can in principle find a Groebner basis and use it to compute everything.  However, I would like a proof that works for all possible sequences, and I  do not see any way to use Groebner bases for that.

Comment: If that is so, then for discrete fields you may already have a constructive proof, no? Because the Buchberger algorithm is finite with decidable output, and (since it cannot contradict classical theory) it is impossible that this output will not fulfill your theorem, so therefore it must fulfill your theorem... Not very elegant perhaps, but constructive nonetheless.

Comment: Fred Richman might be the person to ask. His paper [The regular element property](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1998-126-07/S0002-9939-98-04257-9/S0002-9939-98-04257-9.pdf) seems to touch on your question, and it also refers to the useful book 'A course in constructive algebra' by Mines, Richman and Ruitenburg. (You'll notice the same preference for starting with discrete fields, you probably can disregard the less important constructive 'issues' such as not always knowing whether $k$ equals $\mathbb{Q}$ or perhaps $k=(\mathbb{Q},i)$ (with $i^2=-1$).

Comment: For discrete fields and finitely generated polynomial rings, my (very non-expert) picture is that existence of prime ideals, injective envelopes etc. (the stuff that implies the ultrafilter lemma or AC when stated in full generality) is basically constructive. Gröbner bases help me to understand this, since essentially we only have to test finitely many candidates (don't quote me on this, it is a mental picture :-) ).